# Are questions on the legallity of the use of certain online services welcome?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

As my question here [Legality of scanning a site with SSLLabs Server Test in order to find and report weaknesses](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/97722/legality-of-scanning-a-site-with-slllabs-sll-server-test-in-order-to-find-and-re) doesn't seem to be going down to well, would this question be more welcome here? Because I wouldn't want to ask it here or migrate it here just to have to closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a general form yes, it's on-topic here.  However you should look at existing [hacking](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacking) questions first, particularly [Ethical Hacking](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/304/ethical-hacking).

Comment: Ok, I have had a look at the existing questions here under the [tag:hacking] tag, and I have looked at the question you have linked to, however I have found no question on this site which really looks at what I am asking, so I think that I will post my question. Thank you for your help anyway.